# Vue: how to use a mapState in a computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use `mapState` and have that state then be using a computed property right beneath it.

```
 computed: {
    ...mapState(['features']),

    shouldShowExtras(): boolean {
      if (this.features.hasVIP) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    },
  }
```

I can't pinpoint the issue but all of my tests now come back with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')` .

Before I go through test by test, does the usage seem correct as far as using the mapped state in another computed property?

Comment: That looks correct to me. Are you sure that's the code causing the error?

Comment: That `state` is undefined somewhere most likely means that the store wasn't connected correctly and is unavailable in this component.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should be fine, based on [this](https://jerickson.net/basics-of-mapstate-vuex/) article I found. (It helps a lot to understand what exactly is going on.)

I would guess, that you can find "state.properties"/"this.$state.properties" in your application where the state is "undefined", therefore the properties variable cannot be evaluated/found.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't create getters at vuex and call getter instead of state?

```
getters:{
 features: (state) => state.features
}

 computed: {
    ...mapGtters(['features']),
}
```